# Adding comments to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Pls, i am quiet new to rails, how do i create my webpage to have comments which is attached to  articles, that is each article has many comments and a comment can only belong to an article

Answer (score 2):

(Not a full answer.)

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  # etc.
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  # etc.
end
```

There are a ton of tutorials on the net; you might want to explore some of them and come back with a specific question once you're further along.

You'll also need migrations for each class (or both at once), potentially scaffolding, and so on. Once you have those in place, the rest is fairly straight-forward, but beyond the scope of a single SO question/answer.

Comment: Been able to get past this level, but how do i post it on my article page, so anyone reading te article can see the comments, and also add theirs

Comment: @Elnino Rendering an article's comments as as simple as iterating over `@article.comments`; without knowing what problem you're actually having it's tough to say more. There are a number of ways to add a comment, for example, a form as a nested resource, including the article ID as a comment form parameter manually, etc. I'd recommend trying something, then asking a new, specific question if you run in to difficulties. As I said, though, there are *many* implementations via tutorials everywhere.